# VLOOKUP not working between two sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do a VLOOKUP between two sheets. The source column is a "general" column containing ID's, the lookup column is a "general" column also containing ID's. The formula I'm using:

`VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2) & "", TRIM('[secondfile.xlsx]secondsheet'!$A:$A) & "", 1, FALSE)`

What am I doing wrong? I thought appending "" to the cell would convert the value to a string and compare ok.

-Rudy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP issues can be caused by quite a few problems, so without seeing your source data it's hard to say. I'm also not sure what your second `TRIM` is doing, or what you mean by appending `""`.

However, I notice that you are just looking up against column 1, which suggests that you are just checking to see if the data exist in the other sheet. In this case, why not use the (simpler) `COUNTIF`?

```
=COUNTIF([second sheet]A:A, A1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see it, you cannot append "" to a Range object. Why would you go for a String comparison? My recommendataion: either go for a numeric comparison (faster anyway) or create another "generic" column using the "Text" function to convert numbers into text.

Answer (score 1):

Without trying it, should !$A,$A be !$A:$A ?

Comment: Thanks, but that was a typo as I was just typing this freely.